# Vulkan SDK installer: what are "Debuggable Shader API Libraries" for?

Tags: vulkan

I was installing a new Vulkan SDK.

I'm not sure what this "Debuggable Shader API Libraries" do. The description is very short so I don't understand if I should mark it or not.

Can you help me understand the use case of this component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Debuggable Shader API Libraries" refer to components such as glslang, shaderc, SPIRV-Tools, etc.  The use case might be where you might want to step through one of these libraries with the debugger or collect additional debug info in case there is some sort of problem.  Since this use case isn't that common, the installation of the (large) debug versions of these libraries is opt-in.